# Identify this warty skinned, five-fingers, two-toes Marvel Character

Tags: marvel, character-identification

Five-fingered hands, two-toed feet, pointed ears, ridges on top of head looks like leather halter with buttons or studs, matching wristbands; unsure about the colors. Skin might be green, possibly gray.  Harness is possibly orange or red.  Studs are possibly yellow or gold.  Skin looks warty.

[image: Photo of the goblin-like character described above, it is printed ona piece of fabric]

Comment: any additional context of the source of this image? Game piece, year, etc...?

Comment: Unless someone says otherwise I'd just assume it's some really crappy early Green Goblin merchandise ~ given the fur "bracelets" around it's calves there's a chance the original artist meant those to be split toed boots (rather than feet) & they just got colored in wrong by the later merchandisers.

Comment: My guess would put the gentleman as a breed of troll working against Asgard and Thor.

Comment: From NKCampbell: "any additional context of the source of this image? Game piece, year, etc...?"

The image is of a piece from a Marvel magnetic play set of various heroes and villains, circa 1970.

Comment: I thought it might be [The Jackal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackal_(Marvel_Comics)) but the toes are wrong

Comment: The two toes thing (plus green skin) made me think of [The Abomination](https://www.writeups.org/wp-content/uploads/Abomination-Marvel-Comics-Hulk-Emil-Blonsky-a.jpg)

Comment: In some ways this strongly makes me think of my first wife

Comment: This is Yoda's mutate.. "Yoda Hulk"

Comment: @SS "Yoda smash!"

Answer (score 35):

My nephew asked me to ID it, and I could not figure it out. The piece in question is from a Marvel magnet set for kids.

I contacted the manufacturer, Lee Publications, and this was their official response:

> Those were created over a decade ago. That is a **goblin of Asgard**. They were very minor characters used to fill space.

Hope that clears things up!

[image: Marvel magnet set box art]
[image]

Close-up:

[image]

Comment: That's a hilariously honest answer.  So does this 35 magnet set come with 5 superheroes and 30 goblins?

Comment: A very interesting answer. I can only find a few mentions of goblins in the Thor comics and they don't really look like this.

Comment: Great work. Have a +1 and a little something extra for your efforts :-)

Answer (score 16):

Five fingers, two toes, studded vest - it's a rock troll.

See Ulik as an example:

[image: Ulik, a rock troll, with hairy arms and legs, green clothes and knuckle dusters]

Now Rock trolls are typically orange skinned, but they have been depicted as green on some occasions (like the image shown above).

The troll in the picture looks very similar to the rock troll king Geirrodur, although he normally wears the more regal type robes as shown below.

[image: Geirrodur in pink regal robes and a blue flowing cape]

So I think the image is just generic rock troll.

Answer (score 10):

I think this is Abomination.

[image: Abomination, the green skinned lizard like character with blue pants on saying: I was using my stra-guh-dee!]

[image: A more realistic depiction of Abomination with no clothes on]

Details are on the [Monster Wiki](https://monster.fandom.com/wiki/Abomination_(Marvel))

Comment: I [debated posting this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/206347/can-anyone-identify-this-warty-skinned-five-fingers-two-toes-marvel-character#comment564034_206347), but I can't find any examples of him wearing a similar outfit and the head-shape is different in pretty much every version I've seen from the 1960s and 70s.

Comment: Quite sure it's not Abomination. Abomination usually doesn't wear a lot of clothing, especially not armor, and is far more muscular than the pictured character.

Comment: @Morfildur I think you are correct and the Rock Troll looks more likely, I'll leave it as a possible answer.